# How to remove microsoft sharepoint foundation support?

Tags: microsoft-office, sharepoint

I installed Excel and Outlook from MS Office 2010 Professional Plus, that's the only 2 items I need.

I'm not in a team job with anybody at home, absolutely no need to share or sync.

It's very annoying seeing the Folder Sync at windows explore, and the Shared Folder Synchronization on the right click context menu. The worst thing is the Microsoft upload center is loaded at start, I removed it from msconfig but prefer to uninstall the whole thing completely.

When I go to Add/Remove, change the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation to "Not Available". It accepted and continue and says my changes are done. But it doesn't work. Things are not removed, if open from the Add/Remove, can see this thing still available.

Help!!!

Comment: if you are running Win XP, then XPlite could be able to remove these components. Second, you should try to switch off related services (services.msc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy & paste  following line in **command prompt**, then press enter

```
reg delete HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{6C467336-8281-4E60-8204-430CED96822D} /f
```

source : http://pchatch.com/remove-sharepoint-shared-folder-synchronization/