# How to deinstall sharepoint client

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I want to deinstall MS Sharepoint, which is installed on my VM VirtualBox without any good reason. I looked in the System Settings to deinstall it the usual way, but there Sharepoint is not listed. How can I deinstall it?

Here is a screenshot of sharepoint:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://superuser.com/q/397769/383350).

Comment: It should appear in [Control Panel > Programs and Features](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/uninstall-sharepoint-server-2016).

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Microsoft Sharepoint isn't something that just gets installed, it is not automatically installed by any software, it is something you as the end-user must install.

Comment: @Ramhound: I guess I installed it a long time ago, but can't get rid of it now.

Comment: @harrymc: As I wrote, it does not appear in the "Uninstall or change a program dialog box".

Comment: @CodeIt: Copy & Pasting the command prompt feels a bit uncomfortable... especially since the link to the source is broken... what is the command doing exactly and where does the arbitrary looking hash-looking string coming from?

Comment: @CodeIt: Removing a registry key will not remove the software.

Comment: @Make42: Questions:  (1) When did you uninstall SharePoint and how? (2) What makes it look like SharePoint is still installed? (3) Do you still have the software folder and especially its files `uninstall.exe` or `unins000.exe`?

Comment: @harrymc: 1) I did not say that I uninstalled it. In fact I did not. 2) Sharepoint is regularly opening, saying it want to connect to a server but can't. Stuff like that. 3) Where would I find it?

Comment: 3) In or near the same folder as is the program that is opening. If you don't know that, you may use [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to look at its properties (drag the bull's-eye over the window to find the process).

Comment: @harrymc: Thanks to the Process Explorer, I found it. Apprently it is the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office 14\GROOVE.EXE". There is no `uninstall.exe` or `unins000.exe" in the folder "Office 14". There is a folder "Groove" though. What now?

Comment: This is Groove. To uninstall see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/907504/how-to-uninstall-groove

Comment: @harrymc: (I am from the Linux world most, so I don't know the latest MS-stuff.) Why does it say it is Sharepoint at the logo and it asks me about messages and stuff? It does not look like the images in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groove_Music at all... I am confused.

Comment: User interface changes. SharePoint might have bundled it in. If you find that Groove isn't installed after all, this might be some program masquerading as Groove.

Comment: @harrymc: I posted a screenshot in the question? Are you sure this is Groove?

Comment: This doesn't look like Groove. Are you sure the executable was groove.exe?